# Javascript Fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".screenLoading").fadeOut('slow');
})

setInterval("loadCont()", 500);
//Loaded

function loadCont(){

    $('.container').fadeIn('slow');
    return;
}

function loadLogin() {
    $('.container').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('.log').fadeIn('slow');
    });
}
```

I have the javscript code above and am trying to mimic the effect at http://orinukas.com/SoduBendrija/ .

When I click on the right upper link named 'Nariams', the content with headings and paragraph should fade out and the Sign Up form should fade in.

When I click on that link, content fades, sign up form fades in and content fades in too.

I don't want content to fade in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through the code which you pasted in http://pastebin.com/gQC5MBWL .
i found one issue in this you are using

```
setInterval("loadCont()", 500);
//Loaded 

function loadCont(){

        $('.container').fadeIn('slow');
        return;
}
```

setInterval is calling itself again and again(this will show the content again if you will hide it) so remove this or use setTimeout instead of using setInterval.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below code with you loadLogin function. This should work as wanted.

```
function loadLogin() {
$('.container').fadeOut('slow');
$('.log').fadeIn('slow');
}
```